# punteros de arrays multidimensionales

Tags: c, array, punteros, método

El siguiente código se supone que ordene los apellidos alfabéticamente pero por alguna razón se detiene, el compilador no marca ningún warning, ni error asi que si alguien sabe que pasa explíqueme que pasa porfavor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
double performancecounter_diff(LARGE_INTEGER *a, LARGE_INTEGER *b)
{
  LARGE_INTEGER freq;
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
  return (double)(a->QuadPart - b->QuadPart) / (double)freq.QuadPart;
}


int main()
{
    char apellidos[10][10] = {"Perez", "Bartolome", "Lopez", "Gonzalez", "Jimenez", "McDonald", "Hernandez", "Pulido", "Trejo", "Cernas"};
    char apellidos2[10][10] = {"Perez", "Bartolome", "Lopez", "Gonzalez", "Jimenez", "McDonald", "Hernandez", "Pulido", "Trejo", "Cernas"};

    double tExeIns,tExeShe,c;


    printf("Ordenamiento por Insercion\n\n");
    insert(&apellidos, tExeIns);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}


int compare(char *cadena1, char *cadena2)
{
    int a, b;
    for(a = 0; a < 10; a++)
    {
        if(*(cadena1 + a) > *(cadena2 + a))
        {
            b = 1;
            return b;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}



int insert(char *array, double *secs)
{
  LARGE_INTEGER t_ini, t_fin;


  QueryPerformanceCounter(&t_ini);

    int i, a;
  for (i=1; i < 10; i++) 
  {
    char index[10];// = array[i];
    strcpy(index, &array[i]);
    a = i-1;
    while (a >= 0 && compare(&array[a], index)) 
    {
      array[a + 1] = array[a];
      a--;
    }

    strcpy(&array[a+1], index);
    //array[a+1] = index;
  }

  QueryPerformanceCounter(&t_fin);

  *secs = performancecounter_diff(&t_fin, &t_ini);
  printf("%.16g milliseconds\n", *secs * 1000.0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: no estoy ni siquiera tratando de analizar las indirecciones, pero porque tenes un array bidimensional definido, aunque despues defines solo una dimension? y cuando decis se supone, es lo que crees que deberia hacer?

Comment: dice se supone porque es lo que deveria hacermas no lo hace por el momento y depues declaro una sola dimension porque se supone que tome la dirección por cadena y no por caracter

Answer (score 0):

El programa tenía varios errores. Adjunto la versión corregida. Lo ideal sería que lo compares minuciosamente. Lo que cambié es:

- La matriz (o sea apellidos) es un array de arrays de char, así que cambié el encabezado de la función insert de `int insert(char *array, double *secs)` por `int insert(char array[][10], double *secs)`
- En la misma función eliminé los **&** que no debían ir en la líneas `strcpy(index, &array[i]);` y `strcpy(&array[a+1], index);`.
- También estaba mal la invocación a la función: `insert(&apellidos, tExeIns);` debe ser `insert(apellidos, &tExeIns);`
- Por último, la función `compare` está mal porque le falta el else para finalizar devolviendo cero cuando encuentra un caracter de la primera cadena que es "menor" que su correspondiente en la segunda. Por lo tanto eliminé esta función y usé strcmp que ya existe en string.h, pero para esto tuve que agregar explícitamente la condición **> 0** en la línea `while (a >= 0 && compare(&array[a], index))` que pasó a ser `while (a >= 0 && strcmp(array[a], index) > 0)`.
- Como verificación, luego de ordenar agregué el ciclo para mostrar los resultados:

`for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
    printf("%s\n", apellidos[i]);`

Esta es la versión modificada que funciona:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <string.h>
double performancecounter_diff(LARGE_INTEGER *a, LARGE_INTEGER *b)
{
  LARGE_INTEGER freq;
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&freq);
  return (double)(a->QuadPart - b->QuadPart) / (double)freq.QuadPart;
}

int insert(char array[][10], double *secs)
{
  LARGE_INTEGER t_ini, t_fin;


  QueryPerformanceCounter(&t_ini);

  int i, a;
  char index[10];
  for (i=1; i < 10; i++) 
  {
    strcpy(index, array[i]);
    a = i-1;
    while (a >= 0 && strcmp(array[a], index) > 0) 
    {
      strcpy(array[a + 1],  array[a]);
      a--;
    }

    strcpy(array[a+1], index);
  }

  QueryPerformanceCounter(&t_fin);

  *secs = performancecounter_diff(&t_fin, &t_ini);
  printf("%.16g milliseconds\n", *secs * 1000.0);
  return 0;
}


int main()
{
    char apellidos[10][10] = {"Perez", "Bartolome", "Lopez", "Gonzalez", "Jimenez", "McDonald", "Hernandez", "Pulido", "Trejo", "Cernas"};
    char apellidos2[10][10] = {"Perez", "Bartolome", "Lopez", "Gonzalez", "Jimenez", "McDonald", "Hernandez", "Pulido", "Trejo", "Cernas"};

    double tExeIns,tExeShe,c;


    printf("Ordenamiento por Insercion\n\n");
    insert(apellidos, &tExeIns);
    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
        printf("%s\n", apellidos[i]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```